# Implementing Upsert functionality for Object Flux

Tags: rx-java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, nonblocking

I have a flux request containing objects. Task is to create (if not present) or update (if present) these objects. I have tried achieving this as below :

```
requestFlux.flatMap(entry -> {
        Mono<Optional<MyObject>> existingMapping = myRepository
            .findByIdAndName(entry.getId(), entry.getName());
        return existingMapping.map(optional -> {
        if (optional.isPresent()) {

            MyObject model = MyObjectMapper.updateMyObject(entry, optional.get()); 
            myRepository.save(model);
            return model;
        } else {

            MyObject model = MyObjectMapper.toMyObjectModel(entry);
            myRepository.save(model);
            return model;
        }
        });

    });
```

This doesn't seem to be working for some reason. It is not throwing any error, not creating/updating records or logging the messages that are present inside if/else.
Wanted to know what is that I am missing?

Comment: what does `myRepository.save(model);` return? I mean what is the return type? And do you returning `requestFlux.flatMap(entry -> {....});` this whole chain?

Comment: `save()` method is returning a Mono of type MyObject. I am not returning the whole chain that you mentioned since the return type of the method is different than what is being returned by this chain.

Comment: What do you want to return from the whole chain? I think there is a easy solution

Comment: Hi @Shoshi, `RequestFlux` contains `Objects` which need to be transformed to `MyObjects` by invoking different transforming functions. Then these MyObjects need to be saved via `save()` function. I am also trying to find out the easy way, but not able to figure out yet.

Comment: finally what you want to return actually?

Comment: and you should post your full method code here. and also you have to bind all chains in one chain. otherwise, it will not work. please post full code so that I can show you how.

Comment: This is the whole code, except the return type. Finally the method should just return a Mono<ServerResponse>  stating that processing has been done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212322/discussion-between-viks1010-and-shoshi).

Answer (score 1):

you have to bind all the things in one change. don't break the chain.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> createOrUpdateBulkMapping(ServerRequest serverRequest) {

    Flux<RequestObjects> requestFlux = serverRequest.bodyToFlux(RequestObjects.class);
    List<MyObjects> createdList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<MyObjects> updatedList = new ArrayList<>();

    return requestFlux
            .flatMap(entry -> {

                return myRepository.findByIdAndName(entry.getId(),entry.getName())
                       .flatMap(optional -> {
                          updatedList.add(entry);
                          MyObject model = MyObjectMapper.updateMyObject(entry, optional.get());
                          return myRepository.save(model);
                       })
                       .switchIfEmpty(saveNewModel(entry, createdList));

            })
            .then(ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just("Bulk Create/Update is successful").log(), String.class));
}

private Mono<MyObject> saveNewModel (RequestObjects entry, List<MyObjects> createdList) {
  createdList.add(entry);
  MyObject model = MyObjectMapper.toMyObjectModel(entry);
  return myRepository.save(model);
}
```

**Edited:** as the gist you have provided here: https://gist.github.com/vkrmsngh43/13a8753848893a0f6988d8327f656220 the answer is changed